# Meteor Official Tutorial issue

Tags: meteor

The [Meteor official tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates) does not refer template name, instead uses "body". If you replace "body" by template name it does not work, but it should work by theory.

```
Template.body.helpers //this works, but why?
Template.task.helpers //this does not work, why?
```

There seems to be no explanation for this in the tutorial.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you missed is that template for `<body></body>` is created by default. Inside of body template you've got your each loop, which is managed by Template.body.helpers.

Template.task.helpers can only manage what is used directly inside of `<template name="task"></template>`.

Comment: I think `<head>` isn't actually a real template. The `<head>` is sent in the initial page load so the client can't evaluate it as a template.

Comment: Hmm that may be true. I'll remove `<head>` from the answer, as the question is about `<body>` anyways. Thanks.